# shopping cart in c# does not work correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, shopping-cart, billing, invoice

Actually I am preparing an app in c# like a shopping cart and my bill does not work. When I load the page it keeps loading and shows no error or something else, it just keeps loading and shows nothing. The app is built in c# with asp.net webforms. I have tried without including loop while and i and then it just display one row. I dont know why the loop does not work.

```
public partial class myQueries : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public SqlDataAdapter da;
    public DataSet ds;
    public SqlConnection sqlConn;
    public SqlConnection sqlConn1;

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
       
        string uID = Session["uID"].ToString();

        int userID = int.Parse(uID);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        dt.Columns.Add("requestID");
        dt.Columns.Add("request");
        dt.Columns.Add("solution");
        dt.Columns.Add("qtyn");
        dt.Columns.Add("price");
        dt.Columns.Add("totalprice");

        sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OHDConn"].ConnectionString);
        sqlConn.Open();
        string queryRequest = "select requestID,request,solution,qtyn,price from request where userID = '" + userID + "' and solution is not Null";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = queryRequest;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        int totalrows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < totalrows)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            
           
            dr["requestID"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["requestID"].ToString();
            dr["request"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["request"].ToString();

            dr["solution"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["solution"].ToString();
            dr["qtyn"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["qtyn"].ToString();
            dr["price"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["price"].ToString();
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["price"].ToString());
            int qty = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["qtyn"].ToString());
            double totalprice = price * qty;
            dr["totalprice"] = totalprice;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[5].Text = grandTotal().ToString();
            
            Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();



        }
            

    }

    public double grandTotal()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int nrow = dt.Rows.Count;
        int i = 0;
        double gtotal = 0;
        while (i < nrow)
        {
            gtotal = gtotal + Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["totalprice"].ToString());
            i = i + 1;

        }
        return gtotal;


    }
```

Comment: Please check if your table is locked by some transaction. In that case you need to kill the transaction. If session still persists for that transaction the commit / rollback that transaction.

Comment: You need increment i in end of `while` loop. For example `i++`. Without it, your loop will not iterate to next index and it will never ends.

Comment: you are missing `i++` at the end of the while loop!

Comment: You are binding your grid inside while remove it and bind the result outside of the while.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. You're not incrementing 'i' within your while loop.
2. You're binding your grid within the while loop which is generating your data.

I would suggest the following changes:

1. Extract a method that returns a DataTable and set that as the DataSource for your GridView
2. Wrap the code that is binding the data to the GridView in a !IsPostback check.  This will help when it comes to acting on events in the GridView.

**Example Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData().DefaultView;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[5].Text = grandTotal().ToString();
    }
    
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    string uID = Session["uID"].ToString();

    int userID = int.Parse(uID);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add("requestID");
    dt.Columns.Add("request");
    dt.Columns.Add("solution");
    dt.Columns.Add("qtyn");
    dt.Columns.Add("price");
    dt.Columns.Add("totalprice");

    sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OHDConn"].ConnectionString);
    sqlConn.Open();
    string queryRequest = "select requestID,request,solution,qtyn,price from request where userID = '" + userID + "' and solution is not Null";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = queryRequest;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    int totalrows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < totalrows)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["requestID"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["requestID"].ToString();
        dr["request"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["request"].ToString();

        dr["solution"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["solution"].ToString();
        dr["qtyn"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["qtyn"].ToString();
        dr["price"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["price"].ToString();

        double price = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["price"].ToString());
        int qty = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["qtyn"].ToString());
        double totalprice = price * qty;

        dr["totalprice"] = totalprice;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        i++;
    }

    return dt;
}

public double grandTotal()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int nrow = dt.Rows.Count;
    int i = 0;
    double gtotal = 0;
    while (i < nrow)
    {
        gtotal = gtotal + Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["totalprice"].ToString());
        i = i + 1;

    }

    return gtotal;
}
```